# SUM mysqli y PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Hola tengo un pequeño problema al momento de obtener el resultado final de la consulta.

```
$qty = '0';
$resSQL = "SELECT * FROM live_records WHERE ordenp = '".$ordenes."' ";
$resCON = mysqli_query($db, $resSQL);
while ($resROW = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resCON)) {
$qty += $resROW['age'];
}
echo $qty;
```

La variable $**ordenes** obtengo el resultado de la izquierda y quiero sumar lo de la derecha

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siempre me arroja el ultimo resultado aun teniéndolo en el mismo while

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si borro el parámetro (*WHERE ordenp = '".$ordenes."'*) me suma todo lo que esta en esa tabla y no es lo que se desea.

Realizo por otro lado un echo a $ordenes para verificar si esta trayendo todo los campos y efectivamente me trae todo los campos antes y después de la consulta a la tabla.

Comment: Porque no intentas sumar la edad directamente en MySQL con **SUM**, ```SELECT SUM(age) AS `qty` FROM live_records WHERE ordenp = $ordenes```, otro detalle, si la columna *ordenp* es de tipo **int**, no hace falta las comillas. Te aconsejo también usar sentencias preparadas.

Comment: Lo he intentando realizar con la consulta directa y aun me sigue apareciendo el mismo resultado. La columna es tipo varchar por el instante. Lo de la sentencias preparadas si lo estoy estudiando ya sera en una nueva version porque lo tengo que repasar el tema.

Comment: Que resultado te debería de dar, seria más fácil de ayudar. Cuando haces esto ```WHERE ordenp = $ordenes```, ```$ordenes``` seria **18958** o  como?

Comment: Al realizar la consulta deberia de sumar todos los numeros que estan a lado del numero que acabas de escribir. es decir 639 en el caso de la imagen arriba. 18958 es un numero que dentro tiene el numero 11 en la columna (age) que es la que deseo que se sumen.

Comment: Entiendo, puedes subir una imagen de los registros guardados en la BD de dichos datos. Por qué aun no veo el fallo porque no te está sumando bien. Si te trae todo eso datos con una sola sentencia, te debería de sumar bien. Intenta cambiar ```$qty = '0';``` por ```$qty = 0;``` ya que no es una cadena sino un número.

Comment: Ya habia realizado el cambio $qty = '0'; por $qty = 0; y aun sigue en el mismo, la suma la realiza bien https://prnt.sc/KxUBlCyC5EUQ , Aca tiene el registro de la BD https://prnt.sc/MVLyGnBf9JSw Le estuve dando un buen rato y por varios metodos por POO por sentencia preparadas y aun asi no me deja

Comment: Pero de alguna forma debes filtrar esos datos para la sumo, ya sea por fecha, estación, u otra columna con relación, si lo haces uno por uno no te va a funcionar. Por ejemplo si haces ```SELECT SUM(age) AS `qty` FROM live_records WHERE estacion = 8``` te sumaria todas las edades con estación 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segun me parece, tan solo haces una consulta `$resSQL` y tan solo usas una vez el valor de `$ordenes`, que seguramente te viene recuperado de algun bucle anterior, quedando remanente el último ciclo de ese bucle anterior en la variable **$ordenes**, y de ahí que tan solo te muestre el último resultado.

La solución pasa por poner el **$qty** por encima de ese otro bucle, y poner ese código dentro del bucle, de forma anidada, más o menos así (voy a ciegas, no tengo el código del otro bucle):

```
$qty = '0';
// Inicio del bucle donde $ordenes va cambiando
$resSQL = "PRIMERA CONSULTA";
$resCON = mysqli_query($db, $resSQL);
while ($resROW = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resCON)) {
    // SEGUNDA CONSULTA
    $ordenes = $resROW['ordenes'];  // PONGO ORDENES PORQUE NO SE EL NOMBRE DEL CAMPO
    $resSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM live_records WHERE ordenp = '".$ordenes."' ";
    $resCON2 = mysqli_query($db, $resSQL2);
    if ($resROW2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resCON2)) {
        $qty += $resROW2['age'];
    }
}
echo $qty;
```

También es probable que ese **$ordenes** te venga devuelto de otra función donde realmente se realice el primer bucle, pero al carecer de tu código completo espero que captes la idea con lo que he puesto.

También pudiera ser que la segunda consulta siempre devolviera un único resultado, con lo que podriamos ahorrarnos el segundo bucle.

También pudiera ser que si conocieramos la estructura de las tablas involucradas lo sacaramos todo con una sola consulta SQL, pues para eso estan también.

Ya nos diras si te ha servido.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, realmente la tengo tal cual lo estas indicando y la variable $ordenes es unico incluso lo cambie a otra realizo un echo despues de la segunda en la segunda consulda coloco un if no un while por lo que me crea un bucle infinito.

Comment: He modificado la respuesta, me equivoqué en dos lugares donde no puse el **2** para apuntar a la consulta y la columna correcta, además del cambio de *while* por *if* en la segunda consulta.  Ya nos dirás si ahora sí funciona, gracias.

Comment: Extrañamente me funciono solamente le coloque el if y dentro del if $qty += $resROW2['age']; Muchas gracias colega que tenga un grandioso dia.